# How to make part of the mesh follow a bone without deforming it

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting

I am rigging a model of a creature which has sort of shields on its front legs, but I don't want those shields to be deformed, when I pose the leg. The rest position looks like this:

[image: rest pose]

But when I use the bone, which controls the lower arm, it turns out like this:

[image: deformed]

How can I make the shield follow the arm without deformation? It's attached to the arm (I can't separate it).

Comment: You need to leave only the weights of a bone that the shield is attached to. It looks like you have weights from other bones on that part of the mesh.

Comment: Anyone knows a quick way to clean the weights from selected bone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like it was stated, you need to remove unneeded vertex groups from the shield.

In **Weight Paint** mode, select the vertices you want to clear. Back in the **Vertex Groups**, click the down arrow icon. There's an option to either remove *all groups* from selected vertices, or only the *active group*. Best to remove all groups in your case and manually add the driving group back.

[image: Remove from All Groups location]

Answer (score 1):

this will remove the selected vertices from all groups except the active one :

- select the shield vertices
- select the vertex groub with the shield-bone name
- run the script

---

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object
verts = [i.index for i in obj.data.vertices if i.select]
act_g = obj.vertex_groups.active
groups = [g for g in obj.vertex_groups if g.name != act_g.name ]
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
for g in groups :
    g.remove(verts)
```

Comment: not that this wouldn't work, but I prefer solutions, where I know, what's going on there and I don't know much about python